# Need help for my array of current timing

Tags: java, arrays, datetime

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;


public class dateTimeArr {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n");
    static String[] now=new String[10];
    static String[] later=new String[10];
    static int a,b;
    static String[] dateTimeArr = new String[20];
    static Date theDate = new Date();
    static String currentDateTime = (theDate.getDate() + "/"
            + (theDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (theDate.getYear() + 1900) + " "
            + theDate.getHours() + ":" + theDate.getMinutes() + ":" + theDate
            .getSeconds());

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        dateTimeArr[a]=currentDateTime;
        System.out.println("What are you doing now?");
        now[a]=input.next();
        System.out.println("You are doing " +now[a]+ " at " + dateTimeArr[a]);
        a++;
            dateTimeArr[b]=currentDateTime;
        System.out.println("What are you doing later?");
        later[b]=input.next();
        System.out.println("You are doing " +now[b]+ " at " + dateTimeArr[b]);
        b++;

    }

}
```

Help me on this. the time just dont want to change. Thanks in advance. Need help on this. really appreaciate the help though. sorry for the ugly post as i'm new in here. 
for example my problem is as follows:

> "I wake up at 7:30:15am"

and

> "I get up from bed at 7:30:15am"

I want it to be like :

> "I wake up at 7:30:15am"

and

> "I get up from bed at 7:31:35am"

Comment: What's the expected behaviour? When it asks what I'm doing now, you want it to print "I ... at 7.30am', if it's 7.30am? That's it?

Comment: Can you describe problem you are trying to solve? Also why did you set delimiter to `\r\n` and use `next()` instead of using default delimiter and `nextLine()`?

Comment: `... the time just dont want to change` why should it, you are setting this date once and never update.

Comment: my programme is actually a bank programme. i want it to be for example   "I deposit 70$ at 8:15:17" and "I withdraw 50$ at 8:15:30" but now the displayed time just keep showing the same timing.

Comment: You need to create a `new Date()` everytime you want the actual time. By the way, consider using `Calendar`, since most of `Date` methods are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning currentdatetime to both dateTimeArr[a] and dateTimeArr[b]:

```
 >> dateTimeArr[a]=currentDateTime;
 System.out.println("What are you doing now?");
 now[a]=input.next();
 System.out.println("You are doing " +now[a]+ " at " + dateTimeArr[a]);
 a++;
 >> dateTimeArr[b]=currentDateTime;
```

Since currentDateTime is set only when you initialize it, it won't change during the execution of your code.

Update
This might be a better approach:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class dateTimeArr {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n");
    static String now=new String();
    static String later=new String();
    static String dateTimeArr = new String();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        String dateTime=getCurrentDateTime();

        System.out.println("What are you doing now?");
        now=input.next();
        System.out.println("You are doing " +now+ " at " + dateTime);

        dateTime=getCurrentDateTime();
        System.out.println("What are you doing later?");
        later=input.next();
        System.out.println("You are doing " + later + " at " + dateTime);
    }

    public static String getCurrentDateTime(){
        Date theDate = new Date();
        String currentDateTime = (theDate.getDate() + "/"
            + (theDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (theDate.getYear() + 1900) + " "
            + theDate.getHours() + ":" + theDate.getMinutes() + ":" + theDate
            .getSeconds());

        return currentDateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreaciate your help even though my post was not  very understandable.

Comment: Don't use `date#getMonth()` `getYear()` ... methods. They are deprecated. Instead use `SimpleDateFormat` like `new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` and format current date. You can easy do it with `format(new Date())`.